# Time and date using localtime function

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get a customized date and time output using Perl.

Can someone help me to get the output as desired?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use POSIX;

my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst) = localtime(time);
$year += 1900;
print "$sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst\n";

$now_string = localtime;
print "$now_string\n";

$date = strftime "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime;
print "Date1 is: $date\n";

$date = strftime "%a-%B-%e", localtime;
print "Date2 is: $date\n";

$time = strftime "%H:%M:%S", localtime;
print "Time1 is: $time\n";

$time1 = strftime "%h:%m:%s", localtime;
print "Time2 is: $time1\n";
```

#### output

```
15, 2, 18, 8, 9, 2017, 0, 280, 0
Sun Oct  8 18:02:15 2017
Date1 is: Sun Oct  8 18:02:15 2017
Date2 is: Sun-October- 8
Time1 is: 18:02:15
Time2 is: Oct:10:1507465935
```

#### Desired output:

```
Date1 is: 06-Oct-2017
Date2 is: 06-10-2017
Time1 is: 23:35:10
Time2 is: 11:35:10 PM
```

Comment: Missing `use strict; use warnings;`. Avoid `-w`.

Comment: Why do you use `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y` if you want `06-Oct-2017`???

Comment: Why do you use `%a-%B-%e` if you want `06-10-2017`??? Why do you use `%h:%m:%s` if you want `11:35:10 PM`???

Comment: You can't pick random format specifiers and expect to get the desired output! Read your documentation (`man strftime`).

Answer (score 0):

Perl has great built-in help. Start by running the command:

```
perldoc POSIX
```

and looking at the strftime section. 
Here is an ISO 8601 style timestamp:

```
schumack@linux2 18> perl -MPOSIX -le 'print(strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", localtime))'
2017-10-07T00:11:41
```

From perldoc POSIX:

```
"strftime"
        Convert date and time information to string. Returns the string.

        Synopsis:

                strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year,
                         wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1)

        The month ("mon"), weekday ("wday"), and yearday ("yday") begin at
        zero, i.e., January is 0, not 1; Sunday is 0, not 1; January 1st
        is 0, not 1. The year ("year") is given in years since 1900, i.e.,
        the year 1995 is 95; the year 2001 is 101. Consult your system's
        "strftime()" manpage for details about these and the other
        arguments.

        If you want your code to be portable, your format ("fmt") argument
        should use only the conversion specifiers defined by the ANSI C
        standard (C89, to play safe). These are "aAbBcdHIjmMpSUwWxXyYZ%".
        But even then, the results of some of the conversion specifiers
        are non-portable. For example, the specifiers "aAbBcpZ" change
        according to the locale settings of the user, and both how to set
        locales (the locale names) and what output to expect are
        non-standard. The specifier "c" changes according to the timezone
        settings of the user and the timezone computation rules of the
        operating system. The "Z" specifier is notoriously unportable
        since the names of timezones are non-standard. Sticking to the
        numeric specifiers is the safest route.

        The given arguments are made consistent as though by calling
        "mktime()" before calling your system's "strftime()" function,
        except that the "isdst" value is not affected.

        The string for Tuesday, December 12, 1995.

                $str = POSIX::strftime( "%A, %B %d, %Y",
                                         0, 0, 0, 12, 11, 95, 2 );
                print "$str\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Perl has great built-in help. Start by running the command:

```
perldoc POSIX
```

and looking at the strftime section. 
Here is an ISO 8601 style timestamp:

```
schumack@linux2 18> perl -MPOSIX -le 'print(strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", localtime))'
2017-10-07T00:11:41
```

Comment: Actually `perldoc POSIX` shows only _there is_ a function called `strftime` but doesn't show in detail how to use it. They suggest to `man strftime` which I second.